# There is no file with URL 'catalogs/wp/MSContentEditor.dwp' in this Web

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, 2019

I deployed a new SharePoint 2016 Farm and when I create a new site collection I receive the error below:

There is no file with URL 'catalogs/wp/MSContentEditor.dwp' in this Web.
this is new installation and database instance SP 2016 connected is on always on and SharePoint connected using an AG
[image]

Comment: Please run the product configuration wizard in server to see if any errors it shows and  provide your SharePoint 2016 build number. In the past, same issues were resolved when stable CU updates were installed in SP 2016 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have installed the latest security update for SharePoint 2016.

- [Description of the security update for SharePoint Enterprise Server 2016: December 8, 2020 (KB4486753)](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4486753)
- [Description of the security update for SharePoint Enterprise Server 2016: December 8, 2020 (KB4486721)](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4486721)

> **But before you patch your farm**, It's strongly recommended to check [Best practice to patch your farm and how to Find SharePoint Farm Build Version.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/)